# trying to compile rdgw - getting make errors

Tags: go, ubuntu

So I try to follow the guide to install this https://github.com/bolkedebruin/rdpgw on my Azure Ubuntu VM

I have installed Golang 1.20 and libpam0g-dev but now when I try running make it does a lot of stuff but ends with this:

```
cmd/auth/auth.go:37:16: undefined: pam.StartFunc
cmd/auth/auth.go:37:70: undefined: pam.Style
cmd/auth/auth.go:39:12: undefined: pam.PromptEchoOff
cmd/auth/auth.go:41:12: undefined: pam.PromptEchoOn
cmd/auth/auth.go:41:30: undefined: pam.ErrorMsg
cmd/auth/auth.go:41:44: undefined: pam.TextInfo
make: *** [Makefile:39: /home/azureuser/git/rdpgw/bin/rdpgw] Error 1
```

I am not much of a linux guy. Ideas?

Comment: well I am not sure exactly what happened, because my .bash_history didn't get saved so I don't see the last commands I made but the export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin
didn't happen so I did it again and now make worked. However make install does install: cannot remove '/usr/local/bin/rdpgw': Permission denied
make: *** [Makefile:46: install] Error 1
I ran it with sudo and it worked, though not sure that's right. Now I should do something with rdpgw.yaml and probably create /opt/rdgw/server.pem and key.pem, but how?

Comment: OK I made the certs via some generic guide, so I hope that's fine.